# Spring security Post Requests

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices

Im following this guide `https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/guide` to set up spring security for my microservice

Im just sending basic POST and GET requests. I can do GET requests but when I try for POST requests I get a 403 error.("Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?")
Im trying to set up basic authentication for my microservice

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default csrf protection is enabled. You'll have to configure all your pages to include the _csrf token for this to work
See here: [CSRF Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-in-action)

You can always disable csrf protection.
If configuring in code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.csrf().disable();
}
}
```

or in XML:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```